# How to reliably set key repeat rate and interval for Apple Silicon Macs on macOS 13 (Ventura)?

Tags: keyboard, defaults

In the past (on Intel based Macs) I've always been able to increase the key repeat rate and decrease the initial delay *beyond* what is possible in **System Preferences > Keyboard** by running:

```
defaults write -g InitialKeyRepeat 11
defaults write -g KeyRepeat 1
```

and then logging out and back in.

However, on a new, fresh install of macOS 12.4 on an M1-based Mac, this wasn't having the desired effect. Even on Ventura, those settings don't work like they do on Intel-based Macs.

After a bunch of digging, I found these (new? additional?) keys in the `com.apple.Accessibility` domain:

```
    KeyRepeatDelay = "0.5";
    KeyRepeatInterval = "0.083333333";
```

I've been able to update them with:

```
defaults write com.apple.Accessibility KeyRepeatDelay -float 0.183333333
defaults write com.apple.Accessibility KeyRepeatInterval -float 0.016666666
```

and confirm the new values by running `defaults read com.apple.Accessibility`.

This *sometimes* *seems* to make a difference, but after logging out and/or rebooting, some of the keys (like `KeyRepeatDelay`) revert to other values.

Has anybody figured out the proper set of `defaults` commands and logout and/or restart actions to get the equivalent of `InitialKeyRepeat 11` and `KeyRepeat 1` to work and "stick" with Apple Silicon based Macs?

Comment: I haven't looked at this in Monterey, but it used to require successful toggling of `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false` first.